# Properties preserved by algebraic morphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is sort of a general question.

I am trying to prove certain pairs of affine algebraic sets are not isomorphic, and I have no clue what kind of invariants under algebraic morphisms I might look for, besides the topological ones.

What are some standard properties of algebraic sets preserved by morphisms?

Of course, ideas on how to prove that a pair of coordinate rings are not isomorphic are also helpful.

Comment: As you probably guessed, this is hard to answer in this level of generality. It's also not clear what level you're working at. That said, here are some obvious ones that come up fairly often: different dimension, one is smooth and one isn't, one is normal and one isn't, different automorphism groups, different group of units, different smooth projective models (if your objects are both curves), ...

Comment: Give us examples of the sort of things you are interested in. Otherwise the only answer to your question is: the invariants of algebraic geometry.

Comment: Ok, I see my question was too general. Say curves in $k^2$. For instance, I would like to know if $Z(y-x^2)$ and $Z(y-x^3+x^2)$ are isomorphic.

Comment: @MarcoFlores One of those is smooth and one is not.

Comment: $Z(y-f(x))$ and $Z(y-g(x))$ are isomorphic for any $f,g$. Both are isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1$.

Comment: @Mohan Thank you! I read the one as $y^2$.